# htaccess regex, allow underscores

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Here is our current regex:

```
RewriteRule ^share/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /v.php?v=$1&hash=$2 [L]
```

This isn't allowing underscores "_" - how do we get this to allow underscores?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can shorten your regex like this as well. Now this will allow `_` also. `\w` is shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

```
RewriteRule ^share/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /v.php?v=$1&hash=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

By adding `_` to both expressions within the braces `[]`:

```
RewriteRule ^share/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /v.php?v=$1&hash=$2 [L]
```